# Count (or sum) the number of the gridpoints from a high resultion 2-D data, that are closest to the nearst gridpoints of a 2-D coarse resolution?

Tags: numpy, geopandas, python-xarray

I have two datasets, the first one is a high spatial resolution, and its values are 0 and 1, and the second dataset has coarse spatial resolution data (its values are not important in my case).

I would like to count the number of gridpoints from the high-resolution data which are closest to the gridpoints of the coarse-resolution data, where the values of the high-resolution data are 1.

In other words, count the number of high-resolution gridpoints with the value of 1, that fall within the pixels of the coarse-resolution data.

Example of the data for coarse spatial resolution data

```
lon = [ 176.25,  176.75, 177.25,  177.75,  178.25,  178.75,  179.25,  179.75]
lat = [-87.25, -87.75, -88.25, -88.75, -89.25, -89.75]
temperature = np.random.rand(6, 8)
coarse_res = xr.DataArray(temperature, coords={'lat': lat,'lon': lon}, dims=["lat", "lon"])
```

Example of the data for high spatial resolution data

```
lon = [176.125,176.375,176.625,176.875,177.125,177.375,177.625,177.875,178.125,178.375,178.625,178.875,179.125,179.375,179.625,179.875]
lat = [-87.125, -87.375, -87.625, -87.875, -88.125, -88.375, -88.625, -88.875, -89.125, -89.375, -89.625, -89.875]
ds_2 = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(12, 16))
high_res = xr.DataArray(ds_2, coords={'lat': lat,'lon': lon}, dims=["lat", "lon"])
```

In the end, I would like to calculate the fraction of the high_res gridpoints/pixels with the value of 1 surrounding the coarse-resolution gridpoint. For example, if the first gridpoint of the `coarse_res` data is surrounded by 4 `high-res` gridpoints and these values are `0, 1, 1, 1` the fraction should be 0.75.

Comment: So these are both regular grids?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado yes, both of them are in regular grids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [`xr.Dataset.groupby_bins`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.groupby_bins.html):

```py
low_lon_edges = np.arange(176., 178.001, 0.5)
low_lat_edges = np.arange(-90, -86.9, 0.5)

low_lon_centers = (low_lon_edges[:-1] + low_lon_edges[1:]) / 2
low_lat_centers = (low_lat_edges[:-1] + low_lat_edges[1:]) / 2

aggregated = (
    high_res
    .groupby_bins('lon', bins=low_lon_edges, labels=low_lon_centers)
    .sum(dim="lon")
    .groupby_bins('lat', bins=low_lat_edges, labels=low_lat_centers)
    .sum(dim="lat")
)
```

Additionally, if the cells nest perfectly (it looks like you're dealing with 1/4 and 1/2 degree data which are both centered on the half cell, so this should work fine) you can just use [`xr.Dataset.coarsen`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/v2022.10.0/generated/xarray.Dataset.coarsen.html):

```py
aggregated = ds.coarsen(lat=2, lon=2, boundary="exact").sum()
```

Comment: cool, Seems the second approach works fine, however for the first approach I receive this error: `ValueError: bins must increase monotonically.` Probably it is because of the negative `Lat` values which actually decrease. any idea? 
Then I can accept your answer

Comment: Seems the latitude order that I defined should be in a correct way, like this (and of course my data are like this):  `[-89.875, -89.625, -89.375, -89.125, -88.875, -88.625, -88.375, -88.125]`. Then everything is correct. 
Thank you again for your clean approaches.

Comment: oh interesting. I guess that makes sense. thanks for the note!